# How do I turn my outcome into a variable?

Tags: python

```
import glob, os
os.chdir("DIRECTORY LIST OF .ACCDB FILES")
for file in glob.glob("*.accdb"):
    print(file)
```

Example of what the output is:

1. Attachment1.accdb
2. Attachment2.accdb
3. Attachment3.accdb
4. Attachment4.accdb
5. Attachment5.accdb
6. Attachment6.accdb

Here is the code I am starting off with. It spits out the list of all the .ACCDB files into my folder directory. But now I want to take all of that data and turn it into a variable. Any help would be most appreciated. I am very new to programming.

Comment: `your_variable = glob.glob("*.accdb")`?

Comment: Yes that worked! Thank you so much! I did var_a = glob.glob("*.accdb") to save my output data as a variable and then when I just turn print(var_a) it calls upon all my outputted data! Yay!

Answer (score 1):

You can assign a variable directly to the return value of `glob.glob`:

```py
accdb_files = glob.glob("*.accdb")
```

Additionally, rather than use `os.chdir` to change paths, you may want to just use the path into the `glob.glob()` argument:

```py
import glob

accdb_files = glob.glob("/example/path/to/attachments/*.accdb")
```

This way, it's easier to read, and you don't need keep the state of the current working directory for other file operations.

Comment: It should be noted that providing the full path to `glob.glob()` will result in the files in the result list also having full paths. However, doing it by changing the current directory first and then only providing a pattern for the filename iteself will result in a list of just the matching filenames.

Comment: Great to know! Thanks so much! After I grab my the file .accdb list of all the files in my directory and turn it into a variable I now need to figure out a way where I can use that in a string. For instance, if you open up one of the Attachment.accdb files there are 3 columns. ID | Requisition ID | Attachment file. How do I create a string of some sort that would be able to list the ID, Requisition ID, and FILE NAME?

Comment: @damon So in the very end I will have a csv file showing what ID and Requisition ID is associated with which Attachment.accdb file. Does this make sense? :( I am trying to have it look like this: 1, 1, attachment1.accdb 2, 2, attachment1.accdb, 3, 3, attachment1.accdb 1400,1460, attachment2.accdb

Comment: @t0ky0banana Please create another question and link to it here.

Comment: @damon silly question but how would I link my new question to this post? I have to wait a day since I reached my posting limit unfortunately. But thanks! I'll be sure to post a continuing question to this post.

Comment: @t0ky0banana You can just comment on your initial question saying something like: _Follow up question https://stackoverflow.com/.../_

Comment: @damon Okay I have made a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59434171/how-do-i-turn-my-results-in-a-variable-and-then-call-data-from-a-accdb-file