# How do I turn my results in a variable and then call data from a .accdb file?

Tags: python

[image]

So I have several Attachment.accdb files in my directory. I need help figuring out the correct python code to first call out to my directory and to list out all the .accdb files ONLY.

So then my output data should look something like this:
Attachment1.accdb
Attachment2.accdb
Attachment3.accdb
Attachment4.accdb
Attachment5.accdb

From there I need to figure out a way to turn my output into a variable that I can call upon later.

I then need to figure out a way to make a connection to the .accdb files and build a list of every ReqID within the .accdb file. This list will hold all the ReqIDs from all the .accdb files.

***The ID and ReqID are from the image link shown above. If I were to open up an attachment.accdb file they consist of the following table information

In the end I will have a detailed list showing:
ID (Unique integer), ReqID, name of accdb file
ID (Unique integer), ReqID, name of accdb file
ID (Unique integer), ReqID, name of accdb file
ID (Unique integer), ReqID, name of accdb file
ID (Unique integer), ReqID, name of accdb file

I am very new to python. But am in need of great guidance and assistance.

Follow up to my previous question [Previous question in regards to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59384385/how-do-i-turn-my-outcome-into-a-variable/59384535?noredirect=1#comment105023641_59384535)

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so you basically need to extract and merge data from files with the same name. Here is the first step

```
import pathlib

my_directory = pathlib.Path("./path/to/my_dir")
paths = list(my_directory.glob("**/*.accdb"))
# If you only want the file names
# file_names = [path.name for path in my_directory.glob("**/*.accdb")]
```

This will give you a list containing the path to all of your files. Now you need to process them, which will look like this:

```
results = {}
for path in paths:
    with path.open() as file:
        for line in file:
            line = line.strip() # To remove the trailing line feed
            # Do stuff with your line to put it into your result
```

Since I have no idea what a `.accdb` file is like I can't really help further. You should either clarify your question or look into it by yourself. What you need to figure out now is:
 - which data structure do you want for you result?
 - what's in a `.accdb` and how to extract the data you need from it to put it in your data structure

Comment: Hi @eraw, I have a file directory just with .accdb Microsoft Access database files. Each attachment.accdb file holds all of our database file upload attachment for our users. We are trying to make this script because right now we are having the issue of our database being slow because our database isn't being smart enough to know which record is pulling which attachment file from which EXACT attachment.accdb file. Instead, it takes so long, because our database needs to query through each and every attachment.accdb file to find the correct uploaded attachment(s) for the record that was called

Comment: So we are hoping to make a script that will make our database a little smarter and faster. By associating the ReqID with the exact correct uploaded attachment(s) from the attachment.accdb files. The picture above in my post is what it looks inside one of the attachment.accdb files. See how each ID and ReqID number is tied and associated with each uploaded attachment(s). :)

Comment: I somehow need the python to read my one entire file directory with my .accdb files and I trying to get it to spit on this result: https://ibb.co/PDXDpP6. Trying to get only the file names and not the entire path of each .accdb file in that directory. Then that whole output result list, I need to turn it into a variable that I can call upon later when I create my final list csv file that needs to include ID, REQID, .accdb file name (not the path)